# Firebase Messaging - Validate incoming background messages based on user logged in

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

I'm creating a chat app (kind of WhatsApp-like messaging) using Flutter.
First, the notifications mechanism is working as intended, whenever I send a message from 1 device to another device, the notification would pop up.

I created a local_notification_service.dart to handle the foreground notification & sending a not

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

class LocalNotificationService extends GetConnect {
  String serverKey ='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static void initialize() {
    const InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(android: AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/ic_launcher"));
    _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }

  static void display(RemoteMessage message) async {
    try {
      print("Display notification");
      // int id = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch ~/1000000;
      Random random = Random();
      int id = random.nextInt(1000);
      const NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
        "mychanel",
        "my chanel",
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.high,
      ));
      print("my id is ${id.toString()}");
      await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        id,
        message.notification!.title,
        message.notification!.body,
        notificationDetails,
      );
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print('Error>>>$e');
    }
  }

  Future<void> sendNotification({
    String? title,
    String? message,
    String? token,
    String? uniqueId,
    String? action,
    String? channelId,
    String? channelName,
    String? channelDesc,
  }) async {
    final data = {
      "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
      "action": action,
      "uniqueId": uniqueId,
      "message": message,
      "channelId": channelId ?? 'my channel id',
      "channelName": channelName ?? 'my channel Name',
      "channelDesc": channelDesc ?? 'my channel description',
    };

    try {
      final response = await post(
        'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
        {
          'notification': {'title': title, 'body': message},
          'priority': 'high',
          'data': data,
          'to': '$token',
          'direct_boot_ok': true,
        },
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'key=$serverKey',
        },
      );
      print('response body : ${response.body}');
    } catch (e) {}
  }
}
```

Then, I'm trying to validate the users in my flutter application whenever they receive FCM notification, here's the logic that I want to create:

1. If the user is not logged in, then the device could not receive the notification
2. If the user is logged in, but the specific user is not eligible to receive the message (in case there are some users with the same FCM token / device registered ) then the device could not receive the notification. I would want to solve this after the point number 1 is succeeded

Here's my main.dart file

```
void main() async {
  await GetStorage.init();

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  GlobalController globalC = Get.put(GlobalController());
  AuthController authC = Get.put(AuthController());
  ErrorController errorC = Get.put(ErrorController());
  ConnectivityResult connectivityResult = ConnectivityResult.none;
  final Connectivity connectivity = Connectivity();
  connectivityResult = await connectivity.checkConnectivity();

  if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi || connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
    // Start FCM
    final fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
    globalC.fcmToken.value = fcmToken ?? ''; //set global fcm Token
    final FirebaseMessaging fcmInstance = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

    NotificationSettings settings = await fcmInstance.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: true,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );


    /* Handle message when in foreground */
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((event) {
      if (globalC.isAuthenticated.isTrue) {
        LocalNotificationService.display(event); //display notification
      }
    });

    /* Handle message when in background */
    if (globalC.isAuthenticated.isTrue) {
      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
    }


    fcmInstance.onTokenRefresh.listen((fcmToken) {

      // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new
      // token is generated.
    }).onError((err) {
      // Error getting token.
    });
    // End FCM
  }

  FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

as you can see, I'm trying to filter the non logged in user when in the foreground using the `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen` with the  `globalC.isAuthenticated.isTrue` validation. And it works (because the default of `globalC.isAuthenticated` is false whenever user is not logged in)

But for the `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage` function does not seems to work with the validation. I've tried to search for the solution in the documentations, youtube but i couldn't find it till this question is made.

How can I make this kind of validation for background message?

Sorry for this newbie question, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you .

Comment: The problem I see is you are listening to fcm messages in your main and only for foreground messages your isAuthenticated will work. As background message handler does not know if the user is authenticated or not. So, do you redirect your user to a different screen when the user is authenticated like a homePage()?

Comment: yes, i redirect the user to specific page after checking for authentication

Comment: add your _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler code please